# Delegate to capture two form submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, jquery-events

Using the following function to capture two dynamically generated form submissions, but is not preventing their submission.

```
$('body').delegate('.edit_faq, .new_faq', 'submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //voodoo
    });
```

I was using the following, using `live`. This works, but live is depreciated and the end result is for this code to end up in a flexible plugin.

```
$('.edit_faq').add('.new_faq').live('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //magic
});
```

Comment: This should work. What jquery version are you using and what browser? A sample on jsfiddle would make it easier to answer, and also making a test case can uncover mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is actually working.

check:

http://jsfiddle.net/peuqU/

press run as jsfiddle sometimes needs a refresh before testing submits.

I have only been able to test it with chrome 23.

Answer (score 0):

Try **on** which is the recommended way, and return false:

```
$('body').on('submit', '.edit_faq, .new_faq', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     //Do your stuff here.

    });
```

As to why the submission still occurs, maybe you have a JS error somewhere in the page?

Comment: why return false and preventDefault?

Comment: See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: That doesn't work. Also, that link clarifies that in this instance `return false` is not needed, as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED--

The problem was that the code required being wrapped on a document onReady:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('submit', '.edit_faq, .new_faq', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //voodoo
  });
})
```

I occurs to me that since live did not require the ready, that maybe this is still wrong?

Comment: this is the solution. also live requires document.ready too if I remember correctly.

Comment: In the first, you are attaching the event handlers to `body` which probably doesn't exist until after the DOM content is loaded.  In the second, the handlers are being attached to the `document` itself.

Comment: SO, I can bypass the need for onready by attaching to $(document)?

Comment: I don't think you should bypass it since there will be no guarantee that it will work consistently across browsers.

Comment: @SoonDead That is how `live` works so it will work across browsers.